# Нет лога /var/log/mysql/log-slow-queries.log в Centos

Tags: centos, mysql

настраиваю mysql, вот что в конфиге /etc/my.cnf

```
[client]port            = 3306socket          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock[mysqld]port            = 3306socket          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sockskip-external-lockingkey_buffer_size = 128Mmax_allowed_packet = 1Mtable_open_cache = 1024sort_buffer_size = 1Mread_buffer_size = 1Mread_rnd_buffer_size = 2Mmyisam_sort_buffer_size = 64Mthread_concurrency = 8log-bin=mysql-binbinlog_format=mixedserver-id       = 1max_connections = 100log_slow_queries = /var/log/mysql/log-slow-queries.loglong_query_time = 2log-queries-not-using-indexesslow_query_log = 1thread_cache_size = 4join_buffer_size = 2Mquery_cache_size = 16Minnodb_buffer_pool_size = 8M[mysqldump]quickmax_allowed_packet = 16M[mysql]no-auto-rehash[myisamchk]key_buffer_size = 64Msort_buffer_size = 64Mread_buffer = 1Mwrite_buffer = 1M[mysqlhotcopy]interactive-timeout
```

perl mysqltuner.pl выдает:

```
[!!] Slow queries: 14% (127K/852K)
```

но ни деректории /var/log/mysql/ ни файла log-slow-queries.log нету.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А точно включили

```
 mysqladmin var | grep slow
```

Comment: извините, а где это вводить?С консоли не получается: mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'mysql> mysqladmin var | grep тоже пусто

Comment: Это утилита и "вводить" ее в консоле, и указать ей правильные пар-ры подключения к бд.

Comment: ух и задачка оказалась...# mysqladmin -u root -pххххххх var | grep slowlog_slow_queries = ON | slow_launch_time = 2 | slow_query_log = ON |slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/log-slow-queries.log

Comment: Создайте директорию /var/log/mysql  владелец директории пользователь от которого запущен mysql.

Comment: ага, заработало, спасибо!